# How to get rid of internal compiler error: Illegal instruction min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MIN__; }

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors

I am seeing this error trying to build a program on red hat 6

> ```
>  include/c++/4.9.2/limits:1558:7: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
>     min() _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT { return __FLT_MIN__; }
>     ^
> ```
>
> Please submit a full bug report,
>   with preprocessed source if appropriate.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Can you update gcc? According to this: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59463 it fixed in gcc 5.0/5.1

Comment: I can't update the gcc version. Is there any other way to do it?

Comment: Then post the code that is triggering the error, and maybe someone can suggest a workaround.

Comment: Try to reduce test case and add "-v" to g++ invocation, and you can see on what stage it crashed, C++->assembler, assembler->object file, linking? If it fails on C++->assembler, you can stop compiler on that stage (flags "-S") and post with original c++ source here with generated assembler.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your compiler, but when I had this problem I did something like:

```
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
#else
#define _GLIBCXX_USE_NOEXCEPT
#endif
```

Unfortunately MSVS doesn't support `noexcept`.